# Creating AJAX endpoints for custom fieldtypes

Tags: add-on-development, fieldtype

I'm working on a custom fieldtype that requires some validation via AJAX, which means I need an endpoint to direct my `$.get()` requests to. I know that accessories support [process_x](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/accessories.html#processing-requests) methods but fieldtypes don't appear to offer anything similar.

As far as I can see my options are to create a module (which otherwise I have no need for) or an extension (ditto, really). I noticed that the VZ URL fieldtype [uses the sessions_start hook](https://github.com/elivz/vz_url/blob/master/vz_url/ext.vz_url.php#L76) for this but that's not ideal as it's adding a little overhead to every single request, even frontend ones.

Is there a better, simpler option that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i know, you cannot do this in a fieldtype in any other way. What i've seen most often is a accompanying module that registers an action so that the method in the module acts as the ajax endpoint.

That's not a huge amount of extra work thought is it really :)

I do fully appreciate what you're saying though, it's a shame it can't all be self contained in the fieldtype :(

Comment: Yep, I expect that's what I'll end up doing, but I thought I'd double check that there wasn't a better way. Cheers.

Comment: Fell free to tick my answer as the correct one ;)

Comment: I've given in and setup a module but I was going to leave the question open for a few days just in case someone has got a cunning workaround that they've not posted yet. Adding `process_x` support for fieldtypes is such an obvious feature request but I'm not even sure where to post a FR these days.

Comment: Pick an ellislab employee, and do firstname.lastname@ellislab.com